# Read pixel information from a WebGL 3D canvas return all [0, 0, 0, 255]

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, arcgis-js-api

I'm trying to complete a goal to get a image copy of a certain WebGL Web software: ArcGIS Scene Viewer. It is using a canvas and I tried this:

```
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
    var resultDOM = document.getElementById("result");
    resultDOM.innerText = canvas;
    var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", {preserveDrawingBuffer: true});
    var pixels = new Uint8Array(gl.drawingBufferWidth * gl.drawingBufferHeight * 4);
    gl.readPixels(0, 0, gl.drawingBufferWidth, gl.drawingBufferHeight, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    console.log(pixels); // Uint8Array
```

But the Array logged in console is always full of [0, 0, 0, 255].
So I'm not in full control of the JSAPI I use to create that canvas, so I can't set `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` when first time initializing the `canvas`, all I can do is after the canvas loaded the map then execute some JS. So how can I get the image I need?

Am I doing something wrong here? I also tried framebuffer, it is also not working:

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl", {
      preserveDrawingBuffer: true
    });
    var framebuffer = gl.createFramebuffer();
    //insert code to get mouse x,y position on canvas
    var top = canvas.offsetTop;
    var left = canvas.offsetLeft;
    var x = ev.clientX - left;
    var y = ev.clientY - top;
    var pixels = new Uint8Array(4);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
    gl.readPixels(x, y, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
    console.log(x, y, pixels);
});
```

The pixel value returned is also [0, 0, 0, 0].

Here's a sample you can try: https://jsfiddle.net/qvtt87ky/
It is always returning a whole black image.

Comment: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-3d-externalRenderers.html

Comment: If the WebGL context is created by a third-party library which you do not control you can update `HTMLCanvasElement.prototype.getContext` to force `preserveDrawingBuffer: true` https://jsfiddle.net/w8cjdyr1/

Answer (score 4):

If you just need an copy of the webgl canvas, the easiest way would be to draw the webgl canvas to an offscreen canvas and extract the pixel data using the CanvasRenderingContext2D.

```
var webglCanvas;

var offscreenCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
offscreenCanvas.width = webglCanvas.width;
offscreenCanvas.height = webglCanvas.height;
var ctx = offscreenCanvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.drawImage(webglCanvas,0,0);
var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0, offscreenCanvas.width, offscreenCanvas.height);

console.log(imageData.data);
```

imageData.data is an Uint8ClampedArray and it will have the pixel data that you are looking for.

Comment: This gives the same result as just using readPixels - sometimes a real color, but usually just [ 0, 0, 0, 255 ]..

Answer (score 1):

Framebuffers are just collections of attachments. You didn't add any attachments so your framebuffers isn't setup.

On top of that if you want to read something out of a framebuffer you have to put data in (render to) the framebuffer. Your example code, even if you added the attachments, wouldn't do that.

Example:

```js
var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");

// Clear the canvas to red
gl.clearColor(1, 0, 0, 1); // red
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

// Make a framebuffer
var fb = gl.createFramebuffer();
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

// Make a texture
var tex = gl.createTexture();
gl.bindTexture(gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex);
var width = 1;
var height = 1;
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.RGBA, width, height, 0, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);

// Attach the texture to the framebuffer
gl.framebufferTexture2D(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, gl.COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, gl.TEXTURE_2D, tex, 0);

// Clear the texture to green
gl.clearColor(0, 1, 0, 1); // green
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

var pixel = new Uint8Array(4);
// Read from texture (because it's attached to the current
// framebuffer
gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
console.log("texture:", pixel);

// Read from canvas to show it's a different color
gl.bindFramebuffer(gl.FRAMEBUFFER, null);
gl.readPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, gl.RGBA, gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixel);
console.log("canvas:", pixel);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

### other

This code makes no sense to me

```
var resultDOM = document.getElementById("result");
resultDOM.innerText = canvas;
```

Appending a canvas as `innerText` just means it's going to try to convert an `HTMLCanvasElement` to a string which will likely just print something like `[object HTMLCanvasElement]` so I'm not sure what that code is trying to do